# Panel Enabled property not propagated

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an ASP .Net web application in my company.
The application contains a composite user control made up of a checkbox, several panels and other controls.

One panel contains severals child controls and especially a custom server control.
The custom server control inherits from TextBox.

A handler is executed when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.
A statement in the handler set the Enabled property of the panel to false.
But the Enabled property of the custom server control is equal to true at PreRender.
Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in my company with several years of experience in ASP .Net programming told me that the following behavior is normal :
When the Enabled property of a Panel is set then the setting is not propagated to child controls.